# Is there a way to stop a send to an individual address if data is missing?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I'm new to Exact Target and as the question implies, is there a way to omit the record from being sent an email if the data used for personalization is missing in the list?

I personally prefer sending out with a default value but in order to fully understand the capabilities of Exact Target, I figured I'd ask.

TIA

**Update:**
Thanks I'll give that a try. Would rather not send an email with missing data so that might work.

Edit - When a system returns an error message, where does it get displayed/captured? Would that be in the B2 section where you would write it into a DE?

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make sure the exacttarget email I've built using ampscript only sends if there are new posts in my RSS feed?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32559/how-can-i-make-sure-the-exacttarget-email-ive-built-using-ampscript-only-sends)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The [raiseError()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/api_ampscript_functions/#RaiseError) AMPScript function will abort a send to a particular subscriber from within an email.  It's important to note, this still counts as a send when it comes to billing.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try. Would rather not send an email with missing data so that might work. Edit - When a system returns an error message, where does it get displayed/captured? Would that be in the B2 section where you would write it into a DE? TIA

Comment: By default, it'll display in Send Preview and get written to the server's error log.  SFMC support has access to that.  Since you're trapping errors you can also capture them with the Send Log or write them to a Data Extension.

Comment: If you RaiseError and stop a send you still get charged for it? I should be shocked but I'm not...

Comment: RaiseError is occurs during the send.  Once the send is queued, you get charged for a send.  Audience Exclusion scripts prevent the email from getting queued in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into getting Audience Exclusion scripts enabled under your account (not standard), and write a 1 line exclusion script to check if the email should be sent. You won't be charged with a send that way.   Have a look at my answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32559/how-can-i-make-sure-the-exacttarget-email-ive-built-using-ampscript-only-sends/).

Comment: Good point.  If your exclusion criteria can be reduced to a true/false statement, then this is by far the easiest.